# How to convert a timezone offset value such as “-0400” to one that has a colon like “-04:00” in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, timestamp, timezone-offset, mysql-5.7

So I have a MySQL 5.7 database that is storing a UTC timestamp as well as the timezone offset in two separate columns. Timezone is in `timezone` and offset is in `offset`.

From what I understand I can potentially get the actual offset calculated non-UTC time by running a command such as this using [`CONVERT_TZ`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html):

```
CONVERT_TZ(`timestamp`,'+00:00',`offset`)
```

But the problem I’m facing is the offset value is being stored without a colon separating hours from minutes like this: `-0400`.

To be able to properly use `CONVERT_TZ` I would need to somehow change `-0400` to `-04:00`, but how? Is there a regex method?

I could potentially do something like this using [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html), but that still seems sloppy:

```
CONVERT_TZ(`timestamp`,'+00:00',REPLACE(`offset`,'00',':00'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the original answer to this question was helpful, a comment left by the user “[Michael - sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50539568/how-to-convert-a-timezone-offset-value-such-as-0400-to-one-that-has-a-colon-l/50539642?noredirect=1#comment88107246_50539642)” was even more helpful. It uses the [`INSERT()` string function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_insert) and with that I was able to devise the following and it works great!

```
CONVERT_TZ(`timestamp`,'+00:00',INSERT(`offset`,LENGTH(`offset`)-1,0,':'));
```

And these are the results using that with the following sample timestamps and related offsets:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 02:34:58','+00:00',INSERT('+0300',LENGTH('+0300')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 07:50:12','+00:00',INSERT('+0400',LENGTH('+0400')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 09:23:34','+00:00',INSERT('+0530',LENGTH('+0530')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 12:16:56','+00:00',INSERT('+1000',LENGTH('+1000')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 16:07:17','+00:00',INSERT('-0200',LENGTH('-0200')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 20:02:05','+00:00',INSERT('-0700',LENGTH('-0700')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 23:33:03','+00:00',INSERT('-1000',LENGTH('-1000')-1,0,':'));
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2018-05-28 23:33:03','+00:00',INSERT('-0000',LENGTH('-0000')-1,0,':'));
```

And here are the results:

- `2018-05-28 02:34:58` with an offset of `+0300` becomes: `2018-05-28 05:34:58`
- `2018-05-28 07:50:12` with an offset of `+0400` becomes: `2018-05-28 11:50:12`
- `2018-05-28 09:23:34` with an offset of `+0530` becomes: `2018-05-28 14:53:34`
- `2018-05-28 12:16:56` with an offset of `+1000` becomes: `2018-05-28 22:16:56`
- `2018-05-28 16:07:17` with an offset of `-0200` becomes: `2018-05-28 14:07:17`
- `2018-05-28 20:02:05` with an offset of `-0700` becomes: `2018-05-28 13:02:05`
- `2018-05-28 23:33:03` with an offset of `-1000` becomes: `2018-05-28 13:33:03`
- `2018-05-28 23:33:03` with an offset of `-0000` becomes: `2018-05-28 23:33:03`

Answer (score 1):

To insert the colon in the offset column you can use the following:

```
CONVERT_TZ(`timestamp`,'+00:00',CONCAT(LEFT(`offset`, LENGTH(`offset`)-2),':',RIGHT(`offset`,2)));
```

Comment: RELPACE would have the problem that it wont work for all timezones that do not align hourly. India is the most important example which is +5:30

Comment: Or... `CONVERT_TZ(\`timestamp\`,'+00:00',INSERT(offset,LENGTH(offset) - 2,0,':'))`... remove 0 characters at len - 2 and insert `:` there, with the [`INSERT()` string function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_insert).